# Is 噷 a common way to express thinking?

Tags: expressions

I'm looking for a way to express "hmmn" as in "hmnn... what should I do?" when I stumbled upon 噷. [In wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_exclamative_particles#cite_note-22), it says that it is a way to 'indicate thinking' but in [baidu](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%99%B7), it doesn't appear to have that kind of meaning but rather conveys a sense of dissatisfaction or in a joking manner.

Is 噷 a common way to express the act of thinking or is there a better choice? Something like: [  ]..., 这该怎么办呢？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

噷 is not the one you are looking for.

In Chinese, we usually say 嗯.

Comment: @RayButterworth Yeah, it has other meanings and pronounciations as well.

Comment: Can I directly use that character in my example sentence? Like: 嗯......，这该怎么办呢？

Comment: @CipherBot Yes, you can

Comment: @CipherBot Or, 额....., mmmm... can also work.

Comment: @RayButterworth 嗯 have more than 3 pronunciations. Including ǹg, ńg, ňg, ǹ, ń, ň according to dictionary. Notice that the tone is write above letter n, and there is no letter e in the pinyin. (Most pinyin IME did require typing `en` instead of `n`, but `n` is the correct way to write its pinyin.)

Comment: @tsh, interesting.  [嗯 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%97%AF) agrees with you.  But the Perapera Chinese Popup browser extension that I looked at is completely different (ēn, èn, and en).